# grunt whitespace/indentation errors

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I tried to modify my gruntfile but am getting a ton of errors about my indentation. Is whitespace always important for gruntfiles? What's the best way to fix these errors, counting whitespaces?

```
$ grunt
Running "newer:jshint" (newer) task

Running "newer:jshint:all" (newer) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

Gruntfile.js
  line 33  col 11  Expected 'options' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 11.
  line 36  col 7   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 37  col 7   Expected 'js' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 38  col 9   Expected 'files' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 39  col 9   Expected 'tasks' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 40  col 9   Expected 'options' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 41  col 11  Expected 'livereload' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 42  col 9   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 43  col 7   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 43  col 9   Trailing whitespace.
  line 44  col 7   Expected 'compass' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 45  col 9   Expected 'files' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 46  col 9   Expected 'tasks' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 47  col 7   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 48  col 7   Expected 'gruntfile' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 49  col 9   Expected 'files' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 50  col 7   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 51  col 7   Expected 'livereload' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 52  col 9   Expected 'options' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 53  col 11  Expected 'livereload' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 54  col 9   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 55  col 9   Expected 'files' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 56  col 11  Expected '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 57  col 11  Expected '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 58  col 11  Expected '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 59  col 9   Expected ']' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 60  col 7   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 61  col 5   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 7 instead at 5.
  line 64  col 5   Expected 'connect' to have an indentation at 7 instead at 5.
  line 65  col 7   Expected 'options' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 66  col 9   Expected 'port' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 68  col 9   Expected 'hostname' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 69  col 9   Expected 'livereload' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 70  col 7   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 71  col 7   Expected 'livereload' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 72  col 9   Expected 'options' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 73  col 11  Expected 'open' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 74  col 11  Expected 'base' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 75  col 13  Expected '.tmp' to have an indentation at 15 instead at 13.
  line 76  col 13  Expected '<%= yeoman.app %>' to have an indentation at 15 instead at 13.
  line 77  col 11  Expected ']' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 78  col 9   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 79  col 7   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 80  col 7   Expected 'test' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 81  col 9   Expected 'options' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 82  col 11  Expected 'port' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 83  col 11  Expected 'base' to have an indentation at 13 instead at 11.
  line 84  col 13  Expected '.tmp' to have an indentation at 15 instead at 13.
  line 85  col 13  Expected 'test' to have an indentation at 15 instead at 13.
  line 86  col 13  Expected '<%= yeoman.app %>' to have an indentation at 15 instead at 13.
  line 86  col 13  Too many errors. (21% scanned).

✖ 51 problems

Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: It's just jshint complaining that your indentations aren't as neatly formatted as it would like. The only way to make it stop producing those errors is to fix the whitespace and continue to use proper whitespace to avoid it happening again, or it might be possible to set jshint to ignore messy whitespace, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: so it's a jshint specific thing. grunt doesn't care about whitespace right?

Comment: I don't believe so. I get errors like that all the time because I use tabs and forget that the others on my project use spaces, but everything still runs.

Comment: You can tell the jshint task to ignore your indentation errors by removing `"indent"` from the `options` object in its configuration. I can help you more if you post the jshint config code from your Gruntfile. You can read more about JSHint options [here](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/)

Comment: +1 for just fixing the whitespace. This all comes down to consistency in your code. I will say, don't tell jshint to ignore whitespace... if you really don't want it checking the indentation in the Gruntfile, then tell jshint to ignore the Gruntfile.

Answer (score 6):

Comment out the 'indent' property in the .jshintrc file, or perhaps in the package.json.  Doing a global find on the word 'indent' should get you there.

I find white space really adds to the readability of code, particularly JS.  So much so, that I don't know that it should be linted at all, particularly since it has no affect on how the JS is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting the indent errors from 'lint'.

If you have an 'eslintrc' file you can remove the following line
from the rules key value pairs

' indent: [2, 2, {"SwitchCase": 1}],'

Comment: I found that the indentation is working well in some part of our code but some part is weird. So this trick is working well. It will be nice of course to pass the test.